# how to use for loop in batch file programming

Tags: loops, batch-file

i want to create a auto run backup of data. for this i want to register all the ocx and dll in system32.i want to use loop for this becuse it is easy when we add new dll we dont need to write extra code for that in batch file. the following code is working fine but i want to use loops.

```
Set "tempFile=msdbrptr.dll"
Set "tempPath=%rootPath%%tempFile%

if not exist %tempPath% @ copy controls\%tempFile% %tempPath%
regsvr32 %tempPath%


Set "tempFile=scrrun.dll"
Set "tempPath=%rootPath%%tempFile% 

if not exist %tempPath% @ copy controls\%tempFile% %tempPath%
regsvr32 %tempPath%
```

how we do this using for loop..

Comment: `for %%A in (%windir%\system32\*.ocx %windir%\system32\*.dll) do (regsvr32 %%A&regsvr32 /i %%A)`

Comment: in the above code i am copying from controls folder and registering in system32..    for %%A in (%windir%\system32\*.ocx %windir%\system32\*.dll) do (regsvr32 %%A&regsvr32 /i %%A) where we define control folder in this code

Comment: No such thing as a control directory. Control Panel is a virtual folder and doesn't have files in it. You've also edited my code so it will no longer work by removing a backslash.

Comment: i am saying that you are selecting dll and ocx from windir and registering in sys32... i want to copy dll and ocx from external folder and register into sys32 or syswow32 which is doing in this line    if not exist %tempPath% @ copy controls\%tempFile% %tempPath%
regsvr32 %tempPath%    where  rootpath is rootpath= %SystemRoot%\System32\"

Comment: Forget variables, talk in plain english. I don't know what you think is in your variables (that, at least some, are needlessly defined. How do you propose telling which folder to copy into?

Comment: okk... simply i have a folder in where my setup is installed. name as control. i am creating a auto run backup. for that i crating batch file. when the auto run data is run in new computer firstly it will register all the library files in that system.. so for this i am creating a control folder which have all the dll and ocx file. the batch file copy the dll from that folder and register in sys32 or syswow32.. the above code i mention is work properly what i want.but there is problem when i will add new dll so i have to also modify the batch file.. i think now it is clear...

Comment: Put 64 bit in one directory and 32 bit in another. `copy "c:\controls32\*.*" "%windir%\syswow64\*.*"` etc. Thenrun the other command I gave changing for 32 and 64 bit. `for %%A in (%windir%\system32\*.ocx %windir%\system32\*.dll %windir%\syswow64\*.ocx %windir%\syswow64\*.dll) do (regsvr32 %%A&regsvr32 /i %%A)`. I use 32 bit so I don't know which regsvr32 are there.

Comment: the above code is working but after coping the all files it will registering other file and popping a message box dll register in server and register comctl32.ocx  etc ... how it will exit after only registering selected files....

Comment: Use the /s switch for silent. `regsvr32 /s %%A`

Comment: @noodles : no effect after putting /s.

Comment: if %rootpath% == %SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\ (

    copy  dependency\*.*  %SystemRoot%\syswow64

    ) else (

    copy  dependency\*.* %SystemRoot%\System32
    for %%A in (%dependency\*.ocx %dependency\*.dll ) do if not         exist    (regsvr32/s %%A&regsvr32 /i %%A)

    )error: dll is loaded but, but dll entry point was not found. the file can't be registered.

Comment: I think you are lucky to even have loaded a file. It doesn't mean anything. Ignore it. And the line of code posted did not work - it's wrong - stop using variables. Only COM DLLs can be regserved. .NET and dynamicly linked dlls work differently. So most DLLs will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (
"msdbrptr.dll"
"scrrun.dll"
) do (
   if not exist "%rootPath%\%%~a" (
      copy "controls\%%~a" "%rootPath%"
      regsvr32 "%rootPath%\%%~a"
   )
)
pause
```